# Can't modify folder/files

Tags: permissions, shared-folders, windows-server

I can't modify some shared folders and files when accessing them from another computer (let's call it PC1). The files are in PC2, and if I open a remote desktop connection to it, I'm able to perform any modifications I want. However, if I access the shared folder from PC1, I can only read it but I can't modify anything.

The permission currently set is "Full control" to "Everyone", for the folder, all sub-folders and files (so I can make modifications when logged in PC2, as expected).

There is one user in the network who can modify the files when accessing the shared folder from PC1, so I really have no idea what could the problem be. This user is not listed on any group at PC2, at least not explicitly.

Does anybody have an idea of what could my problem be? Thanks in advance.

Obs: PC1 runs Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, PC2 runs Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise

Comment: What are the permissions on the *share*?

Comment: Thanks very very much @MichaelKjörling !! I checked the permissions on the share and only one user was allowed to modify the folder, although everyone could do it locally. Now it works just fine, thanks a lot!

Comment: That's good that it worked. Let me add it as an answer so that the community can vote on it as well as the question can have an accepted answer, indicating the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is typical of a situation where file system permissions don't match the permissions of the share.

If you want a person (actually, an account) to have a given level of access to something through a share, then both the file system permissions *and* the share permissions must allow that level of access to the account in question.

In other words, if the file system permissions allow read/write access, but the share permissions only allow read-only access, then by accessing the file through the share you are limited by the more restrictive (the share's) set of permissions.

The fix is to **set both the share and file system permissions appropriately** and make sure they are in sync. Both sets of permissions need to allow the desired action for it to be possible to do through the share.